# How to implement a shape selection panel for rendering in PyQt5?

Tags: python, graphics, pyqt5, panel, qgraphicsscene

I'm designing graphic editor. As a scene for drawing, I need to use exactly QGraphicsScene. I implemented adding rectangles and ellipses to the scene with two buttons.

I need to implement dragging the faigures from the panel to the canvas, approximately as in the picture:[Shape Selection Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVe5q.jpg)

What widgets or buttons can I use for this custom panel? Maybe there is an information an example with the implementation of a similar panel?

The program code with the implementation of adding shapes and the interface image:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys                                                                                                                      

# window class
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        wid = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Paint with PyQt5")

        # setting geometry to main window
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)


        # Defining a scene rect of 400x200, with it's origin at 0,0.
        # If we don't set this on creation, we can set it later with .setSceneRect
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 400, 200)

        # Set all items as moveable and selectable.
        for item in self.scene.items():
            item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

        # Define our layout.
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        up = QPushButton("Rect")
        up.clicked.connect(self.add_rect)
        vbox.addWidget(up)

        down = QPushButton("Elips")
        down.clicked.connect(self.add_elips)
        vbox.addWidget(down)

        view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)
        hbox.addWidget(view)

        wid.setLayout(hbox)

    def add_rect(self):
        rect = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 200, 50)
        rect.setPos(50, 20)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.scene.addItem(rect)

    def add_elips(self):
        ellipse = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
        ellipse.setPos(75, 30)
        ellipse.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        ellipse.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.scene.addItem(ellipse)


# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# showing the window
window.show()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Image of interface:
[Image of interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEiqT.png)

Comment: @Dmitry your question is unclear. In the first image you're showing there is a *selection area* that is used to *select existing items*, but you're talking about a panel that allows drag and drop of objects in the scene. These two things are completely unrelated. Please try to be more clear.

Comment: @СергейКох I need a menu bar that is located outside the scene from where I can take a shape and drag it onto the scene by mouse. As in the Paint program or drawio.

Comment: @Dmitry you need to create a subclass of QWidget (or QPushButton/QToolButton, if you want a similar aspect), create a QDrag object in the `mouseMoveEvent()` and implement proper `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent` and `dropEvent` overrides in the target scene. Do some research on drag and drop with Qt, starting with the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) and some tutorials [like this](https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt-drag-drop-widgets/).